# Is it possible to set a maven property from ant?

Tags: properties, maven-2, maven-antrun-plugin

I tried to use the maven-antrun-plugin to check in a first execution if a file exists and then set a property accordingly. In another execution (another phase) of the antrun-plugin I want to make use of the property. But the property set in one execution cannot be used in another execution since it's an ant and not a maven property and doesn't get propagated.

Is it possible to propagate the ant property to maven or in other words set a maven property from ant?

Using another Maven build like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848742/change-properties-in-pom-xml-at-runtime-with-maven-ant-tasks-is-it-possible) is not an option.

Another way that might work somehow would be an external build.xml but that's not an option too, because I have to keep things in one pom.

I've read about using [GMaven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040778/parent-properties-inside-maven-antrun-plugin) to set a Maven property but I would like to stay with ant.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14430122/435605

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of version 1.7 of the maven-antrun-plugin it is possible according to the [plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html) (see exportAntProperties). So, I guess, in earlier versions: it's not ;-).

Answer (score 1):

you can redirect your strategy to activation of different profiles depending on the existence of the file instead of antrun-plugin:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>notExist</id>
        <activation>
          <file>
            <missing>target/maven-archiver/notExist.properties</missing>
          </file>
        </activation>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo>not exist</echo>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>

<profile>
    <id>exist</id>
    <activation>
      <file>
        <exists>target/maven-archiver/pom.properties</exists>
      </file>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo>not exist</echo>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

You can use [activation profiles maven features](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to distinguish between one configuration and another according the activation criteria.

I use the antrun-plugin in example only for do the echo

Comment: Hi Michael and thanks for your effort. But my question is about property propagation from the maven-antrun plugin to the main maven execution and not about profile activation.

Comment: But @Michel's answer still seems to address your intended aim, which seems to be "to check... if a file exists and then set a property accordingly". A profile can be activated based on the file's existence, and the property can be set in the profile.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with even a default value. Example setting `install.path` with echo:

```
<plugin>
    <!-- Workaround maven not being able to set a property conditionally based on environment variable -->
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
                <target>
                    <property environment="env"/>
                    <condition property="install.path" value="${env.INSTALL_HOME}" else="C:\default-install-home">
                        <isset property="env.INSTALL_HOME" />
                    </condition>
                    <echo message="${install.path}"/>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Note that if you try to use `${install.path}` in another `maven-antrun-plugin`, they must have the same version.