# How can I use a default value if an environment variable isn't set for resource filtering in maven?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am using resource filtering to replace some ${values} in a property file.

e.g. the file contains
PROPERTY=${VALUE}

I want ${VALUE}  to be replaced with environment variable $VALUE which works well if $VALUE is set when the build runs. Awesome.

However, these env vars are only set in our official build environment (by Jenkins) and not in developer builds so the ${values} are left in the property file after filtering which can break stuff. I'd rather not require env vars in developer environments as that always leads to fragile dev builds and whiny devs.

**How can I use the environment variable value if its set and use another default property value if the env var isn't set?**

From my testing it works the other way around by default, in that properties set in the pom will override environment variables for the purpose of resource filtering.

Thanks

Comment: You can see my reply here for a similar question
[How to identify and set a missing environment property in Maven?][1]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24456751/1877108

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting default values for custom Maven 2 properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899274/setting-default-values-for-custom-maven-2-properties)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I'm using the profile for determining as

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      <property>
        <name>!myproperty</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
    <properties>
       <myproperty>some value</myproperty>
    </properties>
  </profile>
  ...
</profiles>
```

Please note

1. The `activeByDefault` is set to true with purpose to enable it by default.
2. The `!myproperty` means this property is missing or not existed.
3. If the `myproperty` is not existed, just use the `myproperty` defined at the `properties` instead.

You may see further information at http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

I hope this may help to achieve your requirement.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment.  I removed the <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault> so that it would activate based solely on the property value and I changed it to <name>!env.myproperty</name> so it would pick up the environment variable.  But now it works perfectly.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach does not work when you have other profiles invoked explicitly. In this case implicit profile invocations are not triggered...

Comment: It's just a default value. Why is maven so complicated?

Comment: What if I want to set default values for multiple variables? I've tried repeating the <name> tag, which didn't work

Answer (score 4):

Have the same issue in our development group when using an environment value to denote a file system path - specifically difference between linux and windows.

Based on the other solution on the same question:

```
<profile>
    <id>MY_VAR default value</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>!env.MY_VAR</name>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <env.MY_VAR>default value</env.MY_VAR>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Comment: Using a profile has a bit disadvantage - won't run when running another profile, even when set as default. You need to explicitly request this profile when running other profiles.

Comment: A better solution would be to use ant, as it exports the variable for all to know. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36770198/435605