# MAVEN: How Do I Pass a -D System Variable to Test

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables

I'd like to set a system environment variable to be visible by Java code in the unit tests of a Maven project.  I tried this:

```
mvn -Dfoo=bar clean package
```

But that doesn't seem to take.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510690/environment-variable-with-maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a Maven Property in your pom.xml

Check the Properties section of http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Activation

or maybe this question might help [How to identify and set a missing environment property in Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043313/how-to-identify-and-set-a-missing-environment-property-in-maven)

**Edit**: You can also set an environment variable in the  section of a plugin like  the surefire plugin: [Environment Variable with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510690/environment-variable-with-maven)

Comment: So no way to do it on the command line?  The reason I ask is because I am using this to pass a config parameter to the underlying Java tests.  Ah got it, thanks, the last edit got it.  Cheers.

Comment: However, it looks like from these links that the path to getting an System env variable into the test code from the command line through Maven is not implemented.

Comment: Yep, I think that's right.  I believe you can only set Maven system variables through the command line. Maven handles Environment variables completely different.  I only way I know to set env vars through maven is in the pom.

Comment: Cool, so I decided just to use a unix environment variable to store the data I wanted, then used `System.getenv("foo")` which is all good for the app.