# How to define conditional properties in maven?

Tags: maven, maven-2

For instance, I would like to have property `Configuration` set to `${env:AAA}` if there is an environment variable `AAA` and to some other constant value if there is no such environment variable.

How do I do it in maven 2?

Comment: So you'd like to set a property conditionally?

Answer (score 12):

It appears as though you [activate a profile conditionally](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)...

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>environment</name>
        <value>test</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

The profile will be activate when the environment variable is defined to the value `test` as in the following command:

`mvn ... -Denvironment=test`

Comment: I do not get it. Do you mean maven does not have property conditions? If I have 10 properties and I want to allow overriding each one through the environment, then how many profiles should I define?

Comment: Depends on your build system. If the 10 properties are mutually exclusive, then it appears you need to define 10 profiles. However, I would suggest reviewing your logic if this is the case.

Comment: And to test for its absence: `<name>!my.variable.which.could.be.missing</name>` https://earlyandoften.wordpress.com/2011/02/09/disable-maven-profile/

Comment: A useful alternative is to do it at whatever is calling mvn. For example you might have more power in your shell script to conditionally set environment variables . It's what I ended up doing after reading this answer. Specifically I added a couple lines to my gitlab .yml file that exported an environment variable, then passed them in to mvn via the -D flag.

Answer (score 11):

On the off-chance that a system property is acceptable, you can simply define the property in your POM file and override when required:

```xml
<project>
...
  <properties>
     <foo.bar>hello</foo.bar>
  </properties>
...
</project>
```

You can reference this property elsewhere in your POM by referring to `${foo.bar}`. To override on the command line, just pass a new value:

```
mvn -Dfoo.bar=goodbye ...
```

Answer (score 10):

You can set a property conditionally using maven-antrun-plugin. Example setting `install.path` + echoing the value:

```
<plugin>
    <!-- Workaround maven not being able to set a property conditionally based on environment variable -->
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
                <target>
                    <property environment="env"/>
                    <condition property="install.path" value="${env.INSTALL_HOME}" else="C:\default-install-home">
                        <isset property="env.INSTALL_HOME" />
                    </condition>
                    <echo message="${install.path}"/>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Note that if you try to use `${install.path}` in another `maven-antrun-plugin`, they must have the same version.